# Please give hint to find the sum of this series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

can anyone give me some hint how to find this series's sum?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}$$
I know that by the ratio test, I can find that it is convergent. 
But in order to find its sum, I may need some analysis technique which I don't have. thanks.

Comment: $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: To answer without directly recalling some expansion, see that Taylor's theorem is applicable here to set up a differential equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}=e^z,\quad z \in \mathbb{C}.
$$

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa I am still in the middle of Calculus 3, so I would like to know where is this coming from? do you have a reference or a proof so that it would help me understand?

Comment: @Tmm OK. Here is a route. Set $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$, then we have $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ and by a change of index $f'(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ that is $f'(x)=f(x)$. This yields $(e^{-x}f(x))'=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f'(x)=0$ giving that $e^{-x}f(x)=C$, for a certain constant $C$. But $e^{-0}f(0)=1\cdot 1=1=C$ then  $e^{-x}f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=e^{x}$ that is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=e^x$ as announced.

Answer (score 4):

$$e^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}=1-e^{-1}=\frac{e-1}{e}$$

Comment: The OP asked for a **hint**.

Comment: @flybynight Just because the OP asked for a hint does not restrain us from providing full answers, just as asking for full answers does not restrain us from providing hints.

Comment: @SimpleArt They're different, and you know it. There's very little to be learned, and there's little satisfaction to be gained, from being given a full solution. The OP probably didn't want to be robbed of the satisfaction of solving it for themselves. But, if you're more interested in showing how clever you are than helping others learn....

Comment: @flybynight it depends on each individual question, OP, and subject.  I have seen many cases when hints were dissatisfying and full answers more or less magnificent, and the reverse just as true.  In essence, neither of us can determine how the OP feels.